# How to handle powershell Advanced function ErrorAction parameter?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

How can I properly use **ErrorAction** parameter with my Advanced function? For instance I have such function:

```
function test1 {
[CmdletBinding()]
param([string]$path = "c:\temp")

$src = Join-Path $path "src"
$dest = Join-Path $path "dest"

Copy-Item -Path $src $dest -Recurse -Verbose
write "SomeText"
}
```

Lets assume the source path **$src** does not exist. And I am executing this function with **ErrorAction = Stop**:

```
test1 -ea stop
```

I expect that the error will be thrown and I will **not** see "**SomeText**" message. But I got it:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\temp\src' because it does not exist.
At line:5 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path $path\src $path\dest -Recurse -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\temp\src:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

SomeText
```

I could add **ErrorAction** parameter to **Copy-Item** cmdlet inside the **test1** function, but *I want to be able to explicitly set it to the function to enable/disable error action behavior*.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this behavior. Which version of PowerShell is this? Does it make a difference if you use the full parameter name (`test1 -ErrorAction Stop`)?

Comment: Likewise, not reproducible in PowerShell 5.

Comment: I discovered that w/o **Verbose** parameter added to **Copy-Item** it works fine (stops straight after the error). But with **Verbose** parameter it does not work.  PowerShell v.5

Comment: Hmm explicit preference variables must prevent automatic passing... helpful. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$PSBoundParameters` and alos check `$ErrorActionPreference`

```
function test1 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string]$path = "c:\temp")

    $src = Join-Path $path "src"
    $dest = Join-Path $path "dest"

    $errorAction = $PSBoundParameters["ErrorAction"]
    if(-not $errorAction){
        $errorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
    }


    Copy-Item -Path $src $dest -Recurse -Verbose -ErrorAction $errorAction
    write "SomeText"
}

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
test1

$ErrorActionPreference = 'continue'
test1 -ErrorAction Stop
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to place validation events for input parameters instead, like this:

```
param([ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})][string]$path = "c:\temp")
```